# Display time only from datepicker

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsdatepicker

I have a NSDatePicker and am trying to get only the hour...can this done?  The web references to setting:

`datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;`

but I don't see that option anywhere - it appears to be an iOS only feature.  How can I do this for a desktop cocoa based app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`NSDatePickerElementFlags`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePickerCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDatePickerElementFlags), which you set for your picker using `setDatePickerElements:`

```
[datePicker setDatePickerElements:NSHourMinuteSecondDatePickerElementFlag];
```

or

```
[datePicker setDatePickerElements:NSHourMinuteDatePickerElementFlag];
```